Issue with leaving the allocated memory in C++, signal 11
This is a code I'm writing for a homework with online checking system.
Works on the example given and my own short examples, but the checking system says that it ran incorrectly and ended due to signal 11.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    string mn;
    string x;
    char y;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        if(x!="DELETE")
        {
            cin >> y;
            
            if(x == "APPEND")
            {
                mn = mn + y;
            }
            
            else if(x == "CHANGE")
            {
                mn.pop_back();
                mn = mn + y;
            }

            else if(x == "PUSH")
            {
                int p = mn.find(y);
                if(mn[p] == 'Z')
                {mn[p] = 'A';}
                else
                {mn[p] = char(int(mn[p]) + 1);}
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int u;
            cin >> u;
            mn.pop_back();
        }
    }
    cout << mn;
}

I don't see how possibly could I leave the allocated memory.
Update
I fixed it by replacing a.find() with a loop basically doing the same thing somehow, yet still I don't understand why this version wasn't working.

you have segfault somewhere, likely out of bounds string access, the suspects are pop_back from empty string, and find returning npos

Signal 11 means your program crashed with segmentation fault, not necessarily anything to do with memory. Likely candidate is PUSH handling - you never check whether find() returned actual index or std::string::npos.

Feed an input that fails into Matt Godbolt's little baby and the -fsanitize=address,undefined compiler option will tell you pretty much exactly where the wheels came off. For a small program like this, you should have little trouble tracking backwards from the crash to where the lug nuts where loosened.

You're assuming all operations succeed, but you need to check.   std::string::push_back() has undefined behaviour for an empty string and std::string::find() returns npos if the substring is not found.   Part from memory issues, operations on streams can also fail and - if the error flags are not cleared - subsequent read operations encounter the same error repeatedly. The "online checking system" presumably providing a range of good and bad input to check if your code handles unexpected input - and your code makes no attempt to validate input and recover from bad input.


I fixed it by replacing a.find() with a loop basically doing the same thing somehow, yet still I don't understand why this version wasn't working.

If you had posted your loop replacement that gave you a working version, I could explain why the loop works and how it is different than the string::find operation.
Whenever using functions that can result in edge cases, you should protect your code by handling them to avoid errors or undefined behavior.
The std::string::find reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) says

for a non-empty substring, if pos >= size(), the function always returns npos.
and gives an example on how to identify this problem:

if (std::string::npos == n)
The npos reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) says

static const size_type npos = -1;
This is a special value equal to the maximum value representable by the type size_type. The exact meaning depends on context, but it is generally used either as end of string indicator by the functions that expect a string index or as the error indicator by the functions that return a string index.

The std::string::pop_back reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) says

The behavior is undefined if the string is empty.

Even if you hadn't looked in depth at these references, you could still try to find edge cases and put in print trace code (or just work in a debugger) to understand why the code behaves in unexpected manners.
See https://www.ideone.com/RlZ0ee
for an example of how to add print trace statements. It shows stdin:
APPEND
c
APPEND
e
PUSH
c
PUSH
Z
DELETE
1

and stdout (showing that program stopped before processing rest of inputs):
i:0  APPEND:c  mn: c
i:1  APPEND:e  mn: ce
i:2  PUSH:c
i:2  PUSH:c  mn: de
i:3  PUSH:Z
p == npos = -1  DANGER: ACCESSING MEMORY OUTSIDE OF STRING CHARS
i:3  PUSH:Z  mn: de9C@�O�PUSHD �+a��@�O�@k��`�����������O�z
a�@�y�����#�@�O��y�yH5ܞy����
�O��A-a�Y�+a��@�O��@�O�JO�QO�bO�vO��O��O��O��O��O�!O�3����d@@8�*a�  �@kNkN
����O��O���O�|1he�=�w~|)���<x86_64

This garbage indicates that the code was no longer printing a legitimate std::string. Just as with arrays, we don't usually expect array[-1] to be acceptable; and the same applies to strings. Here is your program with trace statements added:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string mn;
    string x;
    char y;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        if(x!="DELETE")
        {
            cin >> y;
            if(x == "APPEND")
            {
                mn = mn + y;
                cout << "i:"<< i << "  " << x << ":" << y << "  mn: " << mn << endl;
            }
            else if(x == "CHANGE")
            {
                mn.pop_back();
                mn = mn + y;
                cout << "i:"<< i << "  " << x << ":" << y << "  mn: " << mn << endl;
            }
            else if(x == "PUSH")
            {
                int p = mn.find(y);
                cout << "i:"<< i << "  " << x << ":" << y << endl;
                if( p == string::npos)
                {
                    cout << "p == npos = " << p << "  DANGER: ACCESSING MEMORY OUTSIDE OF STRING CHARS" << endl;
                }
                if(mn[p] == 'Z') {
                    mn[p] = 'A';
                }
                else {
                    mn[p] = char(int(mn[p]) + 1);
                }
                cout << "i:"<< i << "  " << x << ":" << y << "  mn: " << mn << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int u;
            cin >> u;
            mn.pop_back();
            cout << "i:"<< i << "  " << x << ":N/A" << "  mn: " << mn << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << mn;
}


To avoid undefined behavior with the pop_back, check to see if the string is empty(). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty.

You mentioned leaving the allocated memory. FYI, The string class often allocates memory and append operations can sometimes result in a deallocation and re-allocation of memory to add in the appended string which is an expensive operation in a high performance computing environment. Also, depending upon the compiler and OS, an exception causing a crash might not clean up that memory. Leaving  allocated memory after a program crash was common in the early days of Windows. Logging out or rebooting the PC usually solved that problem by starting with a fresh set of unallocated memory.

Documentation quotes are not code. In the future, please format them using blockquotes instead. On the toobar, the blockquote is indicated by the button with the quote character image. Manually, you can indicate the blockquote content by using the greater than sign (>) at the left margin of the quote.
